# Hiding a div with specific text as content

Tags: css, dom, html, hide

I've got a DIV I want to hide, but I cannot give it a specific ID... actually I cannot change the text of the DIV, since it is retrieved from a database, but I can add some html before it AND I know the exact text content of the DIV.

It's something like:

```
<div class="this_div">content_of_this_div</div>
```

So, I thought that maybe looking for the specific content, then taking the div and incapsulating it in a hidden div could work... or something similar... any idea?

thanks

Comment: what language are you using? php? javascript? ...?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it, just CSS & HTML tags

Answer (score 2):

If you can insert other HTML around it then you can use another div to hide it

**Using CSS and HTML**

```
.hidden { display: none; }   
...  
<div class="hidden"><div class="this_div">content_of_this_div</div></div>
```

**Using HTML and Inline CSS**

```
<div style="display: none;"><div class="this_div">content_of_this_div</div></div>
```

Comment: True. I just assumed it was to be displayed then hidden. But of course, not necessarily.

Comment: If he's only able to add html tags (I have no idea if that's true), it might be worth suggesting that he add `<div style="display: none; /* or */ visibility: hidden;">` instead of using the `<div class="hidden">`, but if he can indeed add css as well, yours is the better option.

Comment: having some kind of .hide class is a common feature of many stylesheets. Chances are it already exists, and he doesn't have to add anything to the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in your own div would seem most sensible.

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <div class="this_div">content_of_this_div</div>
</div>
```

then hide your div:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.display="none";
```

Or, use jQuery. If that is only instance of class, you could do

```
$(".this_div").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to be able to select it without giving it a specific id, you can do a number of things. Make an empty div with an id before, then use the direct sibling selector:

```
#divid+div {}
```

or use many other css selectors to accomplish same

But I do reccomend the aforementioned external div technique over this